# Winzip command line in c programming

Tags: c, unzip, winzip

I wanted to unzip the file using winzip command line using c programming and i have written the following code but after executing it is showing that the **system** command couldn't identify internal or external command

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include<conio.h>
  #include <string.h>

 void fmuUnzip() {
char fmuFileName[100], path[100],strFinal[100];
char unzip[512]="wzunzip";
printf("Enter fmuFileName\n");
gets(fmuFileName);

printf("Enter path of the fmuFileName\n");
gets(path);
strcat(unzip," ");
strcat(unzip,fmuFileName);
strcat(unzip," ");
strcat(unzip,path);
//printf("The string is : %s",unzip);
system(unzip);
 //getch();
 }

 void fmuLoad() {
 fmuUnzip();
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
 fmuLoad();
}
```

Comment: Try running `wzunzip` on your commandline, you should get the same error.

Comment: Ya I am getting same error

Comment: @moffeltje i am getting same error in command prompt also even though i have installed winzip in my system

Comment: Well, that's the problem. Restart computer or find executable or install again

Comment: Did you try to pass the full path for the program `wzunzip` (`char unzip[512]="/full/path/to/wzunzip";`) ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta **C:\Program Files\WinZip\WZUNZIP.EXE** this is the path for **wzunzip** command how to include in the program.can you help

Comment: remember to put double quotes around the path, `\"`

Answer (score 1):

Especially in a Windows system where new programs are not automatically members of the system path, you should use the full path of the command.

In your example, you should write :

```
char unzip[512]="\"C:\\Program Files\\WinZip\\WZUNZIP.EXE\"";
```

note the `\\` to include a true `\` in a C string, and the initial and ending `"` to force the `system` call to see the path as a single word - thanks to @willywonka_dailyblah  for noticing it

Comment: or do i need to change path variable as given in the site http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/288/

Comment: put double quotes around the path, `\"` - because "Program Files" has a space inside and that means the shell will look for "C:\\Program"